# I have installed pgAdmin4 but still don't have python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web repository

Tags: unix, centos7, pgadmin-4

I have installed pgAdmin4 on Centos7 but and wanted to run the next commands

```
cat >> /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/config_distro.py << EOF
LOG_FILE = '/var/log/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.log'
SQLITE_PATH = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.db'
SESSION_DB_PATH = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/sessions'
STORAGE_DIR = '/var/lib/pgadmin4/storage'
EOF
python3 /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/setup.py
```

but I don't have the pgadmin4-web repository in python3.6/site-packages
I don't have it in python2.6 either.

Comment: why you don't use the postgresql yum repository ? https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-rpm/

Comment: `Python2.6` is old.... Why do you think you need to mention that the files are not there too ?